# problem in login with default /bin/fish shell in gdm

Tags: linux, bash, login, gdm, fish

I set `fish` as default shell for my user in Linux.
`/etc/passwd` file:

```
mlibre:x:1000:1000::/home/mlibre:/bin/fish
```

and now, in `GDM` I can't login with my user (`mlibre`). `GDM` prints some error.

I turned back to `/bin/bash` and it's fixed.
Anyone know why? And how to fix it?

Linux distribution: Arch

Comment: Is `/bin/fish` present in `/etc/shells`? what is the "some error"?

Comment: yeh. i was wrong.
there is a fish in /use/bin/fish and another one in /bin/fish.
/bin/fish not work. and i don't know why.
but i set to /usr/bin/fish and it's work.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a `fish` in `/usr/bin/fish` and another one in `/bin/fish`.
But `/bin/fish` is not listed in `/etc/shells` file.
`/bin/fish` not work. and i don't know why.
I set default bash to `/usr/bin/fish` and now it's work fine.